# Docker remove not working

Tags: docker

My container is:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                  TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
node-test                   0.1                 7c7e55a3196b        11 minutes ago      667.8 MB

I try remove:

$ docker rm 7c7e55a3196b
Error response from daemon: No such container: 7c7e55a3196b
```

If I inspect the container:

```
$ docker inspect 7c7e55a3196b
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:7c7e55a3196b1e986715076c4a19b8925d0264311deec16427248abfee47b5d7",
        "RepoTags": [
            "node-test:0.1"
        ],
...
```

It's working well but not docker rm.

I work on OSX Yosemite.

My docker version:

```
docker --version
Docker version 1.12.0, build 8eab29e, experimental
```

Answer (score 6):

`docker rm` is used to remove **containers**, listed with `docker ps`

`docker rmi` is used to remove **images**, listed with `docker images`

Here if you want to remove your image, you should use :

```
docker rmi 7c7e55a3196b
```

Answer (score 2):

docker images is showing you images

to rm them use `docker rmi <your image>`

**EDIT**

some useful tips :

`docker images -q` Give you the list of your images ID only,

so you can `docker rmi $(docker images -q)` to delete all of them.

you can add `-a` for the hidden images